# Temporary array defined inside for loop and assigned to a pointer belonging to an array of pointers

Tags: c++

Here i have initialised a temp arr inside a for loop and assigned its address to a ptr belonging to an array of pointers but as we come out of the for loop the data stored in that address is lost. And if we print the value at that address it shows garbage value. How to fix this?

```
int n;cin>>n;
int* ptr[n];
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    int k;
    cin>>k;
    int arr[k];
    for(int j=0;j<k;j++){
        cin>>arr[j];
    }
    ptr[i]=arr;
}
```

Comment: *How to fix this?* -- Since the question is open-ended, use `std::vector`, since that is the standard way in C++ to declare a dynamic array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to allocate memory for this pointer manually:

```
int *arr = new int[k]{};
```

Otherwise, you are taking the address of an array that is local to the scope of the loop, which dies at the end of the loop.

Note that when you are done with the dynamically allocated memory, you need to delete it manually as well:

```
delete [] arr;
```

Of course, if you don't have access to the loop local name `arr`, you can delete the memory via `ptr` instead.

Also, this construct:

```
cin >> k;
int arr[k];
```

is a variable-length array and is not allowed in standard c++.